# Retrieving facebook graph data for android native app

Tags: java, android, facebook, graph

I'm creating a android game that integrates with facebook to retrieve their photo and first name and other information using the graph, I've found out how to retrieve their photo using the below code which works perfectly but I'm struggling to find working examples of extracting other information like first_name etc...

The code I'm using to retrieve the photo and display it in a ImageView is below.

```
public void showPhoto(View v) {
    try {
        ImageView MyProfilePicImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.temp);
        URL MyProfilePicURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=normal&method=GET&access_token="+ access_token );
        Bitmap MyprofPicBitMap = null;

        try {
            MyprofPicBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(MyProfilePicURL.openConnection().getInputStream());
            MyProfilePicImageView.setImageBitmap(MyprofPicBitMap);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've searched high and low but can't seem to find information on how to retrieve the other information using the graph, other information meaning first_name etc... including here on the facebook developer website (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) but can't find a working example.

Can anybody show me a working example to retrieve the first_name of the user so I can display it in a textview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using this url`"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token="+accessToken` you can get your friends which contains thier names and ids to get info about any of them just use `"https://graph.facebook.com/"+yourFriendId+"?access_token="+accessToken'
this will return json that you can parse and use
Example

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(token);
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // to get the response string
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                // used to construct the string
                String res = "";
                for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                    res += line + "\n";

                }
// here we will parse the response
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(res));
                JSONArray data = obj.getJSONArray("data");
int len = data.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    JSONObject currentResult = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = currentResult.getString("name");
                    String icon = currentResult.getString("id");

                    // do what ever you want

                }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: you can specify the fields you want to get like this me/friends?fields=birthday,name this will return birthday if its available you can use graph API explorer to find the right url to use by specifying the fields you want from left area https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Dbirthday%2Cname&version=v2.2&

Answer (score 0):

If you change your request URL to just `/me` (i.e. `https://graph.facebook.com/me?type=normal&method=GET&access_token=...`) you'll get all available profile information for the currently authenticated user.

This JSON object should have `first_name` and `last_name`, among other attributes foud [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

Check out this [handy API explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me) to play around with what you should be seeing.